# Image import into magento

Tags: php, image, magento, import

I have a bunch of images of the products for my shop. Now, i don't want to add all the images one by one because it would be very time consuming. The images' file names are equal to the product name, so I tried this:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
{       $fileName = $_product->getName();
        $filePath = $importDir.$fileName; 
        if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
        try {
            $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, 'image', false, false);
            $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, 'small_image', false, true);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
     }
      $_product->save();
}
?>
```

The code itself would work if I would take one specific image, but it does not work with the name. All the images are inside the import folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nave not mention the extension of the image `(i.e., .jpg, .png, etc)`.

You have to add the extension for the `$filepath`

```
 $filePath = $importDir.$fileName.'.png'; //if all images are png
```